# Common Configuration.yaml Nav stack help

Tags: ros, navigation, base-laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am in the process of configuring the navigation stack and for the common configuration yaml file, i don't exactly know what i should put for the frame name of the laser scanner. I am currently using the sick_tim310 laser range finder. Contacted the guys who made the driver for ros and they said to come here.

-------------------------------- common_configuration.yaml ----------------------

```
obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
footprint: [[x0, y0], [x1, y1], ... [xn, yn]]
#robot_radius: ir_of_robot
inflation_radius: 0.55

observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor point_cloud_sensor

laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: FRAME_NAME, data_type: LaserScan, topic: topic_name, marking: true, clearing: true}

point_cloud_sensor: {sensor_frame: frame_name, data_type: PointCloud, topic: topic_name, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

would the FRAME_NAME be sick_tim310 ? this is the only thing i could imagine it to be. I looked if in the source there was anything specifying the frame name, and the only thing i found was a published frame id that was set to the message header. I don't believe that is what i am looking for.

from my understanding and previous encounterments (for example in setting up the transform) the [child] frame_id i specified for our laser relative to the robots center [base_link] "base_laser" I'm a little confused still by the difference between the frame_id and frame_name.

**EDIT:**
If you are using the sick_tim3xx ros package, the then sensor_frame is **laser**. If you are using a different laser scanner, just go look through the code of the package, and where ever the node is assigned values to the sensor_msgs/LaserScan message, look for what is being assigned to laser.header.frame_id, and whatever is set there (say 'laser'), then put {sensor_frame: **laser**, .....} in the common_configuration.yaml file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/136021/common-configuration.yaml-nav-stack-help/) by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1526 on 2014-03-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-08-07**:
Someone correct me if im wrong. According to @ahendrix 's answer, it seems that it MIGHT be what the frame_id is for the transform publisher which broadcasts a transform from your laser to your base_link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, frame_id and frame_name are the same thing.

You should use the header frame_id from your laser as the sensor_frame when configuring the costmaps.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-03-05**:
well in the transform i set the frame_id to base_laser. is that what it is? or do i need to look in the source code of the driver I'm using?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-06**:
base_laser sounds like the right frame name for your application.